# How should I clear a flask server session with redis?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-session

Should I use
    session.pop()
or
    session.clear()?

Current problem there is:
I tried to session.clear() to end the session, but the session is still there in redis.

I hope:

1. End the current session
2. Delete the relevant session storage in redis

What's the best practice there? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is your real problem. you want to clear session. session.clear() seens to be more designed for this.

Comment: Both do different things, so it depends on what you want to do.